# Jaspersoft Domain Designer: Determined what Y/N should be translated to

Tags: sql, database, oracle, jasper-reports, jasperserver

I have an (Oracle 11g) table with a (single character) "Y/N" flag column. For purposes of simplicity, imagine we're talking about a "Person" table and the column in question is a "Gender Indicator". Without changing the structure of the DB, is there a way to manipulate my result set such that I am able to get "Male" returned for "Y" and "Female" returned for "N"? I have looked into the SQL translate() and replace() functions, but not sure how to do this for multiple rules without having to resort to PLSQL. Any advice would be appreciated.

If this isn't possible via a single , the requirement is for a Domain I am generating in Jasper Reports so any advice on how it may be done that way would help also.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT CASE WHEN Gender_Indicator = 'Y' THEN 'Male' ELSE 'Female' END AS Gender_Indicator FROM MyTable;`

This would give you what you are looking for from what I can tell.

You could also use `DECODE(Gender_Indicator, 'Y', 'Male', 'N', 'Female')`

Answer (score 0):

If you keep gender indicator as Y/N, you can use the ternary if in Jasper Reports inside a text field expression to achieve your goal.

Assuming you have a field in your report (let's call it `genderIndicator`) that can hold values Y or N, then add a text field with the following expression:

```
$F{genderIndicator}.equals("Y") ? "Male" : "Female"
```